# TYPO3 / Formhandler / Make formhandler records editable?

Tags: typo3

Is it possible to make formhandler records editable and even show and sort by 
- lets say - name and lastname in TYPO3 BE?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I lately made a dummy extbase extension for a customer. Formhandler stores its data in these tables. Thus they are accessible as usual in the backend. They are sortable and editable and anything you like.

Comment: Hi Stefan! Would you like to contact me? mail and fon at
netzteil.com

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://typo3blogger.de/newsletteranmeldung-mit-formhandler-turchen-14/ There I have created an example how to create records in TYPO3 with formhandler and Finisher_DB. In newer versions please use Finisher\DB

Here are all properties of the Finisher\DB of formhandler:
http://www.typo3-formhandler.com/documentation/finisher/finisherdb/

Use ifIsEmpty to fill up fields with a default value. F.e. if you don't have this field in your form.

Answer (score 0):

at http://pi-phi.de/formhandler.html I documented (in german) how I used formhandler to generate tt_news records with categories.

the tt_news records needs a confirmation of an admin, so the admin gets a mail